# issues in sample codes on developers.android

Tags: android

There was some sample codes in the resource section, explaining some examples, that now are gone.
i.e http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeMain/index.html

when click on them it takes you to http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html
any help regarding this ?

EDITED:
Issue >>> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33495

Comment: What is your question?  What do you want to do and can't?

Comment: there were tutorials on developer.android i want to use them but i cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is download the Samples from this link http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html and then follow these steps to get it running on Eclipse:

File ->New -> Android Project -> Create Project from existing sample -> Select the version(for which you have downloaded the Samples) -> Select the Sample.

In this way you can import the sample reference program provided by android and it will help you in getting good hold of its API's.

Comment: there was a [colorpicker tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html) on it... :/ but in samples its not available now

Comment: Its still there in the Sample. Check the `APIDemos` sample and inside that you will find the colorPicker example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an Tic Toe Tutorial this series of tutorial may help you to follow http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/introducing-tic-tac-toe-tutorial.html